# Why is my Texture Painting doing this?

Tags: texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

I'm trying to mix two different materials using texture painting. But when I try to paint, I always paint on several faces at the same time.

[image: 1]

It has this weird symmetry-like effect. I just want to paint normally. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have overlapping UVs.
To check them, switch to UV Editing, select your object, enter edit mode then select all (<kbd>A</kbd>).

Comment: It seems like I do have some overlapping UVs. How do I fix them? Do I just unwrap?

Comment: You can redo your UVs from scratch, like create Seams on edges, then Unwrap.
Or you can move them manually, or if they are separated element, repack the islands.

Comment: Okay then. I'll try that and see how it goes.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer! It works!